# Couldn't install SQL Server 2012 on machine with Windows 7 SP1, VS 2010 SP1

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2012

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 RTM on my pc, I have installed Windows 7 SP1, VS 2010 SP1 but it again and again giving this error:

> *A network error occurred while attempting to read from the file:*
>   D:\Microsoft SQL Server 2012
>    RTM\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\x64\sqlncli1.msi
>   Error help link:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40PublishProduct%401316

When I go to the Microsoft link I find

> We're sorry
>   There is no additional information about this issue in the
>   Error and Event Log Messages or Knowledge Base databases at this time.
>   You can use the links in the Support area to determine whether any
>   additional information might be available elsewhere.

How can resolve this, at first i thought adding current user in Display Replay controller making the problem, then uninstalled everything and again tried installing but couldn't succeed. Can anyone suggest what may be causing these problem and possible resolve for it. 
I have also SQL Server 2008 R2 installed which I want to keep simultaneously with 2012

Additional Information's:

Its on local drive i.e on my harddisk, so there should be no error and Its the RTM version of SQL 2012.
I find below logs on C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\

Feature: SQL Client Connectivity SDK Status: Failed: see logs for details Reason for failure: An error occurred during the setup process of the feature. Next Step: Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again. Component name: SQL Server Native Client Access Component
Component error code: 1316 Component log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20121022_164723\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log Error description: A network error occurred while attempting to read from the file: D:\Microsoft SQL Server 2012 RTM\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\x64\sqlncli1.msi Error help link: go.microsoft.com/…

This problem not yet solved, although other people installed SQL2012 with this installer on their PC's. I think something wrong with my PC or some settings i am using.
Please can anyone help me out?

Comment: Check the location of the SQL Server 2012 Setup log for more detailed errors, by default in this location - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\.   As a general troubleshooting task, do you get the same error if you copy the files onto your HDD?

Comment: What is D:\? A local drive, a mapped network drive, a USB thumb drive, a CD, a mapped ISO? Where did you get the installer and what edition of SQL Server 2012 is it? Details, details, details...

Comment: Please edit your original question with the logs, instead of pasting them in comments. My guess is that your source files are corrupt in some way. Copy or extract the installation media again and start over.

Comment: Could it it be the install order? I also have VS2010 Express installed with SQL Server 2012 Express running on a Win7 machine. I installed SQL Server first, then VS. Doesn't VS install a stripped down version of SQL Server? Could installing VS first in fact put files on the system that the SQL Server install is stumbling over?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the troubleshooting options I'd try:

1. Disable antivirus. Man, I hate saying this, but I've seen issues where antivirus took too long to scan a file, and it caused installation problems.
2. Re-download the installation media. I know you've seen other users run this same setup and it's worked, but I've seen enough corrupt downloads that I would try this anyway. It doesn't cost you anything.
3. If D is a network share (a mapped drive), copy the installation files locally before you start.

Answer (score -2):

naturally, two instance of two different version of SQL Server database reside two different machine. if you use development purpose, VM may be a instant solution to gear-up your development.

could you share the event log of the message displaying moment? It may gives some clue!

Comment: You can quite happily have multiple different versions of SQL on a machine

Comment: yep, that also i knew ..two versions can be easily installed in a machine, i guess there's something with my OS cause other people happily installed with this installer